# Setting button.onclick via button click activates on first button press

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I'm trying to create a button that when pressed changes the content of an html page and updates the button to change its next function. However, whenever I use `.onclick` I end up printing the "2" to the console while still on the first press of the button. I've tried using `.click` as well, and the only thing that I can find that works is setting the function directly, however this is untidy and long. I wondered if there was another way to do this with cleaner code.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <script src="Path_To_File"></script>

      <p id="text">
        <!-- text here -->
      </p>

    <button id="b1" type="button" onclick="pageFlip(1)">Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function pageFlip(page) {
  var p = document.getElementById("text");
  var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
  var b2 = document.getElementById("b2");

  switch (page) {
    case 1:
      p.innerHTML = "newText";
      b1.innerHTML = "newText";
      b1.onclick = pageFlip(2);
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log("2");
      break;
  }
}
```

What works:

```
b1.onclick = function changeButton() {
    pageFlip(2)
}
```

Comment: b1.onclick = pageFlip(2); calls pageFlip and assigns what it returns to the event handler

Comment: So how can I set the html property directly then?

Comment: like how you did. You do not need to use a named function. `b1.onclick = function() {pageFlip(2)};`